# COM interop - marshaling unions of value and reference types by overloading interface methods

Tags: .net, com, com-interop, unions

Consider the following method from [PInvoke.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6wyhwt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
union MYUNION2
{
    int i;
    char str[128];
};
PINVOKELIB_API void TestUnion2( MYUNION2 u, int type )
{
    //...implementation is irrelevant...
}
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya9bz4ha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> In managed code, value types and reference types are not permitted to
>   overlap. This sample uses method overloading to enable the caller to use both types when calling the same unmanaged function.

The managed code for the sample is as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=128)]
public struct MyUnion2_1
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int i;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyUnion2_2
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)]
    public string str;
}
[DllImport( "..\\LIB\\PInvokeLib.dll")]
public static extern void TestUnion2(MyUnion2_1 u, int type);  

[DllImport( "..\\LIB\\PInvokeLib.dll")]
public static extern void TestUnion2(MyUnion2_2 u, int type);
```

That's all fine and dandy in P/Invoke, but how do I do that in COM Interop? Obviously I can't just create overloads as the CLR relies on the methods' exact position in the vtable. It's as if I need a COM-method equivalent of `FieldOffsetAttribute`.

Create two interfaces (one for each overload) works, but it's a little awkward...

Comment: This requires violence.  First directed at the dev to get him to fix this.  Next the *fixed* keyword in C# so you can declare the union.  Use Encoding.Default to convert the string by hand, don't forget to zero-terminate it.

Comment: Well I'm the only developer so violence won't be a problem :) I can already see I'll like the two interfaces solution better, but out of curiosity I want to get your suggestion to work. I tried `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] public struct MyUnion { [FieldOffset(0)] public int i; [FieldOffset(0)] public fixed char str[128]; }` (in unsafe context of course) but even accessing the integer doesn't work (nothing happens when I call the method).